# Finger Mesh Doesn't Follow Atmature

Tags: weight-painting

I had a look other questions but non have fixed the issue.

Anyone have any ideas on what the issue could be?

[image]

Comment: I noticed the my hand.L has red weights covering the full hand. could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Hand.L shouldn't have full weights over the hand.

I had to redo auto weights on the hand bone then do auto weights on the finger bones